# What is the difference between "面对" and "应对"?

Tags: vocabulary

I would love a quick overview of the difference btween 面对 and 应对! In particular, I would love to know what you say if you want to use 
以...的太对来应对/面对 这个问题? Is 应对 or 面对 used
in this instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question, "以。。。的太对(态度)来应对／面对 这个问题 ？". If you want to stress on the attitude (positive, negative, responsible, etc), you should use 面对. But if you want focus on the action strategy, then it's 应对.

以积极的态度来 **应对** 这个问题 -> to **handle the issue** with positive attitude (we should not wait here, it's not the end, let's do something!)

以积极的态度来 **面对** 这个问题 -> **thinking of the issue** with positive attitude (it's not so bad, we still have chance, let's more focus on the bright side)

面对 is usually used to describe a situation. Here 面 means "facing -> regarding to".

Meanwhile 应对 is more focus on taking action. 应 means 响应 (respond), 应付(deal with).

One example can be found here: http://jingyan.baidu.com/article/6b97984d9dadef1ca2b0bfe0.html

**面对** 危机我们该如何有效 **应对**

How should we **respond** effectively **(regarding) to** the crisis

You can find more similar cases by searching both words: http://bit.ly/1nRji4a

Answer (score 5):

In my opinions:

面对=to face. One just passively accepts the event.
应对=to act on, to respond. One needs to do something in response to the event.

Answer (score 2):

I would say there no much difference.

If you really want to find something different:
面对：face it
应对：face it and try to solve it

Answer (score 1):

My concise answer:

面对: to face
应对: to cope with

Answer (score 0):

"面對" means "face"; so it simply implies that one does not evade. Yet "應對" is stronger; it implies "面對" and often that one is trying to work solutions out.